# How to access a variable declared inside a method of a class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to acccess a variable declared inside a method in a Class from another Class. My code is something as below:

```
class Profile {
    getData() {
        let data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    }
}
```

And now I want to access it from this Class:

```
class UI {
    listProfiles() {
        let gp = new Profile();
        let arr = gp.getData.data;
    }
}
```

I tried the statement above, but couldn't access that data variable.
Thanks in advance for answering my question.

Comment: Add `return {data}` in getData method

Comment: @NenadVracar thanks! By adding that simple word 'return' made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the class from `Profile` then import it in `UI.js`. Also you need to return from `getData`. Beside replace `gp.getData.data;` with `gp.getData()`

```
export default class Profile {
  getData() {
    let data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    return data;
  }
}

import Profile from './profile.js';
export default class UI {
  listProfiles() {
    let arr = new Profile();
    return arr.getData()
  }
}
```

Working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wlze1s)

Comment: Thank you! this was a better and professional way I think.

Answer (score 0):

Do correct your code

```
class UI {
    listProfiles() {
        let gp = new Profile();
        let arr = gp.getData();
        return arr;
    }
}
```